# Solving $\lambda U^{\dagger}V -\bar{\lambda} V^{\dagger}U = A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given an arbitrary $A \in \mathfrak{su}(n)$, is it always possible to solve for $U,V \in SU(n)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\lambda U^{\dagger}V -\bar{\lambda} V^{\dagger}U = A$?

Update: There was a slip in the question.

Comment: Crossposting: [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/211723/solving-lambda-u-daggerv-bar-lambda-v-daggeru-a). Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is affirmative. By a change of basis, we may assume that $\frac1{\|A\|}A=\operatorname{diag}(iy_1,\, iy_2,\, \ldots,\, iy_n)$, where each $y_j$ is a real number between $-1$ and $1$. Therefore each $y_j=2i\sin\theta_j$ for some real $\theta_j$. Let $W=\operatorname{diag}\left(e^{i\theta_1},\ldots,e^{i\theta_n}\right)$. Then $W-W^\dagger=\frac1{\|A\|}A$. Let $\phi$ be the average of all $\theta_j$s. Take $\lambda=e^{i\phi}\|A\|,\ U=I$ and $V=e^{-i\phi}W$. Now we are done.

Comment: Is it possible to still solve this for $U$ if $V=G$ is given and $\lambda = Tr(G^{\dagger}U)$ for some given $G \in SU(n)$? This case seems much trickier.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\| U^\dagger V - V^\dagger U \| \le 2$ (where $\|.\|$ is the operator norm, say), the answer is: no, not always.

Comment: There was a slip in the question, I should have excluded that from happening.